# Adding data inside the calendar

Tags: jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery FullCalendar (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).
I already 'draw' the callendar but I can't find a way to insert the data I bring from database inside it. 
I'm using a week format callendar and I need to put some appointments on it. I'm reading the documentation but can't figure it out.

My code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calendario</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>   
    <script src='calendario/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='calendario/lang/pt-br.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='calendario/fullcalendar.css' />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //Page is now ready, initialize calenda.
        $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            height: 350,
            header: false,
            firstDay: 1,
            weekends: false,

            events: [
                {
                    title: 'Event1',
                    start: '2016-03-08',
                    end:'2016-03-08T20:00'                  
                }
            ]       
        })
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="calendario"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

No it works but is there a way to use other date format inside `events:[]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert the data add the Events option to your calendar initialization.  You are also missing script elements to include jQuery UI.

Comment: Dont know the other guy erased his answer... Well, I tried this but still not showing anything.